# Azure AD B2C integration with SAML and OIDC

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, saml

We have a .Net 6 website that integrates with Azure AD B2C using OIDC. Login and registration for the website are defined in custom policies in the Azure AD B2C tenant. Azure AD B2C returns a claim that we use for user creation and login for existing users.

The client would like the website to integrate with another platform that supports SAML SSO to Azure AD B2C. Basically, if users are signed in to the website, and by extension signed into Azure AD B2C, and they click a link on the website to take them to the other platform then the user should be signed into the other platform.

My question is if we can mix OIDC and SAML in the custom policies so that logging into the website logs the user into the other platform or does it need to be either OIDC start to finish or SAML start to finish.

I have looked into the Microsoft documentation and it explains how to integrate Azure AD B2C with either OIDC or SAML but I couldn't find anything related to integrating Azure AD B2C with separate platforms that use different protocols.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if understand your use-case correctly - are you trying to onboard external partner as identity provider? And their identity provider uses SAML2 protocol?

If yes, you can look at this official page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Basically you need to use custom policy. In a nutshell, custom policy orchestration flow redirects to identity provider, user authenticates with its own credentials. If successfully, the idp issues SAML token, redirects back to B2C.

And then you can process/transform those claims in SAML token, even create reference/federated user in your b2c (add your own attributes/claims in B2C user management portal) and send claims as JWT token back to your app.

Peter